# Yii2 - How to modify controller action param using a behavior?

Tags: yii2, behavior

I'm trying to change the `$id` param in my controller methods on the fly using `beforeAction` and a `behavior`.  FYI, I'm going to use HashIds and need to convert anywhere I have a `$_GET['id']` that may be hashed back into an integer.

How can I use a behavior to automatically modify my $_GET['id'] on the fly using a **behavior**?

An example action in my controller:

```
public function actionView($id){
    // run code to process $id here back to integer using a behavior
    echo $id; //should be an integer
}
```

My sample url: `http://mydomain/posts/view?id=3QhLp`

(Alternatively, perhaps the better way to do this is to create a custom url rule?)

Answer (score 3):

you should implement a class that extends from the `\yii\base\Behavior` like below

```
<?php

namespace backend\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Behavior;
use yii\web\Controller;

class Transformer extends Behavior
{
    public $id = '';

    public function events()
    {
        return [Controller::EVENT_BEFORE_ACTION => 'transform'];    //mounting the handler to the 'beforeAction' event on the controller.
    }

    public function transform()
    {
        $_GET['id'] = $this->id . "transformed";       //mock method here

        return true;
    }
}
```

Then in your controller, adding the code as follow:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'transformer' => [
            'class' => \backend\models\Transformer::className(), //Modify the path to your real behavior class.
            'id' => Yii::$app->request->get('id'),
        ],
    ];
}
```

then access the `Yii::$app->request->get('id')` in your action, you will see the transformed url param.

Comment: Thanks, great you can access `Yii::$app->request->get('id')` from the controller, However, you can't access `$id` (the param set in the action). If i go about it this way I have to rewrite every single action that uses `$id`.. any way to implement that final step?

Comment: As far as I know, the param in the action method is parsed from the original url using rules in urlManager, not the `$_GET`, unless you can change the original url string in your behavior. May this will help.

Comment: Don't think you can.. and if that's the case, would this be better implemented as a custom url rule? And converting there rather than a behavior?